# How does multi-classing Sorcerer/Bard total spell slots work at lv 20/20?

Tags: dnd-5e, multi-classing, sorcerer, bard, caster-level

I'm curious if I ever managed to get my Sorcerer/Bard to 20/20 what would his spell slots be totaled at? Based on the rules for multi-classing to my knowledge, he'd be considered at a casting level of 40, so would that grant him the ability to cast more than 1 level 9 spell per long rest?

Right now he is at 4/1, and until he is at a total of twenty between his classes I can follow the basic chart, but what do I do after that?

Comment: Generally speaking, you shouldn't accept an answer right away. Over the next day or two, somebody may come up with something you might like better, but already having an accepted answer to the question can discourage people from providing additional answers.

Comment: To be honest, nothing really _"works"_ at lvl 20/20... you're in gods territory there, you can do pretty much what you want.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

### You're on homebrew territory

Multiclassing a character to maximum level in multiple classes is not possible under the base rules. The maximum character level is 20, so the total levels you have in Sorcerer and Bard can't sum up to over 20 either.

In accordance with that, the multiclass spellcaster table (5e PHB, page 165) only goes to level 20 as well, so there is no official answer in the Player's Handbook.

Comment: So then I guess I'd need reference the 3.5's epic rules with my DM?

Comment: @Clarus_Nox I wouldn't personally try to convert 3.5e rules to 5e, but however you choose to do this is up to you and your GM. A character of level 40 is so powerful anyway that pretty much everything goes, I'd say.

Answer (score 24):

## Rules as written, you'll never get to 20/20.

The character will never reach Sorcerer 20/Bard 20 by the rules, because characters stop advancement by level at 20th.

Multi-class characters use the table and rules on on page 164 and 165 of the PHB to determine spell slots. The key point of fact is that a character determines spells *known* for each class *individually*. Take a look at the chart for each class, and make sure that you're not going to miss out on learning 9th level spells by multiclassing (if you care). Just because a character has 9th level spell slots, that does not mean he actually *knows* any 9th level spells.

## What happens after hitting L20?

The DMG has a section starting on page 232 for Epic Boons, benefits characters can gain for earning XP beyond 20th level. Among other choices, one of them can give you more 9th level slots... but just one.

## Can I use older epic rules?

I wouldn't, but if you're feeling brave, crazy, or willing-to-meticulously-rebalance...

One of the key elements of D&D5E is the concept of bounded accuracy. The range of bonuses is much more compressed than it was in prior editions. Stacking a full range of class abilities onto a character is not how the system was designed.

Comment: I was already aware of how my known spells worked, my caster level may be 5 right now & I get 2 lv 3 spell slots but I am still a lv 4 sorcerer with no lv 3 sorcerer spells. That said, I think over half of the sorcerer and bard spells are eligible for both.

Looking at the boons I'd rather just level grind while role playing for the class features than most of those... 

As for rebalancing, I'm both my DM & I are willing to work for that, he likes the challenge of some of my questions, and there have been zero issues working in my 2 homebrew requests(lythari race & fey sorcerer bloodline)

Comment: Yup... I kind of figured you did. That part of the answer was more for others who come across the question. As for the rest, well... you're already stepping beyond the book, so have at it. If you come up with a solution that works, and can clearly describe the benefits and drawbacks, you can come back later and supply an answer to your own question. If you do, just be careful of nets of interwoven house rules - if your proposed solution requires too much divergence, it may not be appropriate for the needle-focused Q&A format of SE.

Comment: @Clarus_Nox Have you ever run a campaign to level 20 in D&D 5e?  Have you ever run a campaign to level 30 in another edition?  Has your DM done either?